# Create new data frame from pairwise from another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I create a new pandas data frame from an existing one using a column pairwise. For example I have a data frame like this. The original data frame is image one.

**Original Data Frame**

[image]

I want to create a new data frame that takes the first sequence as the source and the second sequence as the target till the end of the conversation id. For the person column I want to grab the person who said the source and for the type it should be the type of the conversation id.

**Resulting Data Frame**

[image]

I want the data frame to end up looking like image two.

Comment: please try to give clear text dataframe instead of images. It helps to give you a quicker answer. Also, have you tried anything to solve this?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be clear. Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to solve this. You need to use groupby.transform() and shift(-1).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_id':[1,1,1,2,2],
                   'sequence':['hi','how are you','bye','hi','gone'],
                   'person':['A','B','A','B','A'],
                   'type':['Friendly','Friendly','Friendly','Mean','Mean']})
print (df)
df['source'] = df['sequence']
df['target'] = df.groupby('column_id')['sequence'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(-1))
df1 = df[df['target'].notna()]
df1 = df1[['source','target','person','type']]
print (df1)
```

The output of this will be:

**Original DataFrame**

```
   column_id     sequence person      type
0          1           hi      A  Friendly
1          1  how are you      B  Friendly
2          1          bye      A  Friendly
3          2           hi      B      Mean
4          2         gone      A      Mean
```

**Modified DataFrame:**

```
        source       target person      type
0           hi  how are you      A  Friendly
1  how are you          bye      B  Friendly
3           hi         gone      B      Mean
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help

Comment: It this solved the question, don't forget to click the green checkbox to confirm that this answered your question